# SQL no data found exception not getting executed

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the code which has to execute the exception block when no data is found in the main block. However the exception block is not getting executed even when the query doesn't return any record. The query joins with another table and when the result matches with the query it will pick the 1st record else it has to assign null values to the fields and return the cursor to UI. The count below for the cursor is always 0 and the exception block isn't getting executed .

```
BEGIN
    wf_common.write_debug(vprocname, ' 111=', ts);
    OPEN cinfo FOR SELECT
                       name,
                       phone,
                       alt_phone,
                       email
                   FROM
                       abc
                   WHERE
                       id IN (
                           SELECT
                               id
                           FROM
                               xyz
                           WHERE
                               emp_no = vempno
                       )
                       AND name IS NOT NULL
                       AND ROWNUM = 1;

    wf_common.write_debug(vprocname, 'COUNT' || cinfo%rowcount, ts);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        wf_common.write_debug(vprocname, '222=', ts);
        OPEN cinfo FOR SELECT
                           '' name,
                           '' phone,
                           '' alt_phone,
                           '' email
                       FROM
                           dual;

        wf_common.write_debug(vprocname, 'COUNT' || cinfo%rowcount, ts);
END;
```

Comment: Did you try to run this without exception block?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja yes i did. The result is the same. The cursor returned 1 record when data is found and cursor is empty when no records in the table that satisfies the condition. My requireemnt would be toreturn null values for fields and the cursor should still hold 1 record with empty fields if records werent found.

Comment: If you aren't planning on looping over your results, why open the cursor at all?  Just s`SELECT  COUNT(*)` into an `INTEGER` variable.  Then have an if-else to print your messages.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND` with 
`WHEN OTHERS`

Comment: I did but no change. Still exception block isnt getting executed

Comment: What i think is there isnt any exception which is getting raised by default so you have to raise explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This is a *cursor*. It doesn't raise `no_data_found`. How will you know whether it'll return something or not? You won't until you

- open it
- fetch from it

Then you'll know.

So - unfortunately - you'll first have to check, and then decide what to do. For example (based on Scott's sample schema):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_deptno in emp.deptno%type)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    type cinfot is record (empno emp.empno%type,
  5                           ename emp.ename%type,
  6                           job   emp.job%type);
  7    cinfor    cinfot;
  8    cinfo     sys_refcursor;
  9  begin
 10    -- in order to test whether it returns something, open & fetch
 11    open cinfo for 'select empno, ename, job
 12                    from emp
 13                    where deptno = :a' using par_deptno;
 14    fetch cinfo into cinfor;
 15
 16    -- has anything been found?
 17    if cinfo%found then
 18       -- something has been found - process it
 19       close cinfo;
 20       open cinfo for 'select empno, ename, job
 21                       from emp
 22                       where deptno = :a' using par_deptno;
 23
 24    else
 25       -- nothing has been found; open another cursor
 26       close cinfo;
 27       open cinfo for select deptno, dname, loc
 28                      from dept;
 29    end if;
 30
 31    return cinfo;
 32  end;
 33  /

Function created.
```

Testing: department `10` exists in `EMP` table so - return its contents:

```
SQL> select f_test(10) From dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT
      7934 MILLER     CLERK
```

Department `50` doesn't exist so - return `DEPT` table's contents:

```
SQL> select f_test(50) From dual;

F_TEST(50)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON


SQL>
```